# How to import data frame with character column (RPostgreSQL)?

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

I have a problem with import table using RPostgreSQL. I mean, one column is bigint format, and when I create simple query:

```
df<- dbGetQuery(con, "
                     SELECT euid
                     FROM table
                     LIMIT 5;")
```

I received

```
       euid
1 6.011e+18
2 5.010e+18
3 1.001e+18
4 6.012e+18
5 6.013e+18
```

Of course I do not wat to get logarithic notation. Instead just the same euid number as I have in database.

When I use `options(scipen=999)` I get

```
                 euid
 1 6011000000000000000
 2 5010000000000000000
 3 1001000000000173312
 4 6012000000000000000
 5 6013000000000000000
```

but real euid number in database is

```
          euid
   ---------------------
   6011000000000000150
   5010000000000000240
   1001000000000173341
   6012000000000000117
   6013000000000000119
```

It is possible to import all column in character format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting euid to TEXT should help, as this way it will not be treated as a numeric value.

```
df<- dbGetQuery(con, "
                     SELECT euid::TEXT
                     FROM table
                     LIMIT 5;")
```

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof! You save my life!